# Not all data is transfered via Socket

Tags: c++, sockets

I can't send too large data packets over my setup (currently sending to 127.0.0.1), at about 30kB this functionality starts to fail. For testing I have an application that just starts a Receiver and a Sender, starts two threads, one for the sending, one for receiving, and when both have finished, compares if the sending string is the same as the received string.

```
void SenderThread(int count)
{
    messageOut = "";
    messageOut.append(count, 'A');

    sender->sendData(messageOut);
}

void ReceivingThread()
{
    receiver->ReceiveData(message);
}

main()
{
    receiver = new utility::Receiver();
    sender = new utility::Sender();

    receiver->startSocket(9000);
    sender->connectToSocket("127.0.0.1", 9000);
    receiver->accept();

    for (int count = 100; count < 1024 * 1024; count += 100)
    {
        std::thread sendThread(SenderThread, count);
        std::thread recvThread(ReceivingThread);

        sendThread.join();
        recvThread.join();

        printf("Sent data of length %d ", messageOut.length());
        if (message == messageOut)
            printf("successfully.\n");
        else
        {
            printf("not successfully.\n");
            printf("Length of original message: %d, Length of received message: %d.\n", messageOut.length(), message.length());
            break;
        }
    }
    delete receiver;
    delete sender;
}
```

I have following code for my sending socket:

```
bool utility::Sender::sendData(const std::string & message)
{
    int numBytes = 0;
    int totalSent = 0;

    // Break condition: send() fails, or whole message was transfered

    while (totalSent < message.length() && send(message.substr(totalSent).c_str(), message.length() - totalSent, numBytes))
    {
        totalSent += numBytes;
    }

    return false;
}

bool utility::Sender::send(const char* pBuffer, int32_t lengthOfBuffer, int32_t &numBytes)
{
    numBytes = ::send(connectSocket, pBuffer, lengthOfBuffer, 0);

    if (numBytes == SOCKET_ERROR)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

The receiving side:

```
bool utility::Receiver::ReceiveData(std::string& message)
{
    int32_t numBytes = 0;

    char data[defaultBufferLength];

    // Set to blocking for the first data package

    u_long iMode = 0;
    ioctlsocket(tcpSocket, FIONBIO, &iMode);

    bool success = receive(data, defaultBufferLength, numBytes);
    message = std::string(data, numBytes);

    // Set to non-blocking for the rest of the journey
    iMode = 1;
    ioctlsocket(tcpSocket, FIONBIO, &iMode);

    while (numBytes == defaultBufferLength && receive(data, defaultBufferLength, numBytes))
    {
        message.append(data, numBytes);
    }

    return success;
}

bool utility::Receiver::receive(char* pBuffer, int32_t lengthOfBuffer, int32_t& numBytes)
{
    int32_t flags = 0;

    numBytes = recv(tcpSocket, pBuffer, lengthOfBuffer, flags);
    if (numBytes == -1)
    {
        numBytes = 0;
        if (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK)
            return false;
        else
            close();
    }

    return true;
}
```

The output I am getting is

```
Sent data of length 39200 successfully.
Sent data of length 39300 successfully.
Sent data of length 39400 successfully.
Sent data of length 39500 successfully.
Sent data of length 39600 successfully.
Sent data of length 39700 successfully.
Sent data of length 39800 successfully.
Sent data of length 39900 successfully.
Sent data of length 40000 successfully.
Sent data of length 40100 successfully.
Sent data of length 40200 successfully.
Sent data of length 40300 successfully.
Sent data of length 40400 successfully.
Sent data of length 40500 not successfully.
Length of original message: 40500, Length of received message: 29200.
```

The thing which is the most irritating, and probably the cause of this, is the ::send(...). I can give it 2 MB of char*, and it will just send it in one swoop (but the receiver fails miserably). What can I do about that?

Comment: It is tcp socket, or wich protocol?

Comment: @Rama: The variable is named `tcpSocket`, and he's using `recv` and `send` instead of `recvfrom` and `sendto`, so yes it's TCP byte-oriented stream.

Comment: @SinisterMJ, try to get the las error with ` WSAGetLastError` at the moment of send data to see if there was an error at the moment of send. it could give us more information of what happen with your send routine. If you are using Non-Blocking to send data you should use `select` wait until the socket is ready to write, it's the same case to read.

Comment: Why is `numBytes == defaultBufferLength` a condition in the `while` loop? That doesn't make any sense. Your `ReceiveData` function seems completely broken.

Comment: You should provide a minimal example. As it stands, your question is off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP is a byte-oriented protocol, not message oriented.

`send` does not create a message.  `recv` does not receive a message.  They work on blocks of bytes, and multiple `send` calls can be combined at the network layer (for efficiency) or broken into multiple TCP packets.  In practice, even if you turn off Nagle's algorithm, if a frame is lost at the physical layer and TCP has to retry the transmission, the retransmit will include as much data added to the buffer afterward as it can fit in an outgoing datagram.

So you can't rely on any particular mapping between send calls and recv calls.  The only guarantee is that the bytes are delivered to your socket in the same order they were sent.  If boundaries are important, you have to create them yourself.  Length prefixes are popular in combination with TCP, special framing sequences less so.

You do already have a loop for reassembling messages... but you break out of the loop when you see `EAGAIN` / `EWOULDBLOCK` or a partly filled buffer, and continue processing.  That's a problem, because you only have a partial message at that point.  You need a way to delay processing until you have a complete message.

Comment: To put it very simply, if you want to send and receive messages, you need to: 1) Precisely define what a "message" is and how they're encoded. 2) Write a function that sends a message according to that definition. 3) Write a function that receives a message according to that definition.

Comment: @Remy: That edit was totally inappropriate.  I specifically considered writing "1:1 mapping", but chose this wording.  Also "send calls" does not mean just the `send()` function, but also `sendto()`, `sendmsg()`, `sendv()`, `write()`, `aio_write()`, etc.

Comment: Awesome, that worked. I now sent an int containing the length of the message, and call recv() until I have received that length of data, and in my test it instantly worked for 20 MB of data (which is way more than I need).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to ben-voigt answer, you need to create an higher level message system for your socket, so you can send to the server the message size and on your socket receive method create a session or buffer storage that you append the received data till the message size match the total data received, once that requirement is met then you can process the data